# Programatic build events in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, build

This sounds like fantasy to me but can I make a class in my project that runs methods or something like that when the project is built? Is there an interface or abstract class for that?

Comment: I'm sorry to be a bit sceptic about this, but may we know the reason why ? It might help us providing you other ways to solve your problem.

Comment: I have a base library for an addon framework and I want all the projects that reference that assembly to have custom built events. More precisely, to move all the output files to a folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project files are made up of MSBuild files, you can execute pretty much anything from them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx

Basically you can 'unload' the project file in Visual Studio and edit them with a normal text editor.

Look for this area in your *.csproj files (and some other project types, note that not all project files are MSBuild compatible files):

```
 <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
```

And just add your MSBuild tasks there :)

Comment: I already knew about this but I was looking for a in-project-code way.

Comment: Why not use the PostBuild or AfterBuild event to run a console app from your project? Or just write a custom msbuild task...

Answer (score 1):

As Zidad pointed out, you can edit the MSBuild project file itself.

You can also just add some stuff in your `PreBuild` and `PostBuild` events. Check the project properties pane.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to program MSBuild [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx).
If you want better personalization, you can create someting like a batch or if you want a console or winform application and invoke command line msbuild and do things programatically.

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild has the ability to use custom Tasks, derived from the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.task.aspx) class. Which lets you create custom tasks and hook them into various points as the build progresses.

But it sounds almost like you want something to take actions as the code is compiling, which obviously is impossible because the code isn't compiled yet.